# Rails + cancan: Print debug text inside can/cannot block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, cancan

Rails/cancan enviroment:

Maybe a silly/simple question, but how can I log arbitrary text inside a can/cannot block to the corresponding log file of the current environment (p.ex. `log/development.log`)?

Let's assume:

- I am signed-in as non-admin
- I want to call the action `foo` of `MyObject`
- My `models/ability.rb` looks like this

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      Rails.logger.debug "outside"
      can :foo, MyObject do |myobj|
        Rails.logger.debug "inside"
        true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Why is `Rails.logger.debug "outside"` printed to `log/development.log` but `Rails.logger.debug "inside"` is not, although the action `foo` inside `controllers/myobjects_controller.rb` is called (logging debug text there works of course)?

Comment: Because the block for `can :foo, MyObject` is only evaluated when you test that condition

Comment: I am not quite sure, if I understand you correctly: If I am logged in as non-admin and call the route `myobjects/:id/foo` (p.ex. `http://localhost/myobjects/3/foo`) I would have expected that Rails logs "outside" and "inside" into `log/development.log` - and therefor that condition ist "tested".

Comment: I don't know what controller that route is hitting, or what code is in that controller. Is it even touching any cancan abilities?

Comment: The route hits the `foo` action inside the `myobjects_controller.rb`. So `rake routes` prints
`foo_myobject GET /myobjects/:myobject_id/foo(.:format) myobjects#foo`
So it should touch `can :foo, MyObject ...`, shouldn't it?

Comment: not unless you're calling that in your controller. cancan is completely independent of your routes. https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Authorizing-controller-actions

Comment: Ok, now I got it, thanks. :) I indeed have the corresponding `load_and_authorize_resource` statement(s) in the controller (`has_many`/nested resource scenario here). Seems I have a bug there.